# concatenate values across columns in data.table, row by row

Tags: r, data.table

I have data.table like this:

```
x <- data.table(
       a = c( 1,     2),     
       b = c('foo', 'bar'))
```

I want to add a new column 'key_' that contains the row-by-row concatenated values of a and b separated by '_':

```
   a   b  key_
1: 1 foo 1_foo
2: 2 bar 2_bar
```

For the hard-coded case, there is a simple solution:

```
x[, key_ := paste0(a, '_', b)]
```

How could I achieve this in the more generic case when the columns to be concatenated are given as an arbitrarily long character vector?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Btw, to verify that your new column is a key (in the sense of uniquely determining a row), you can afterwards do `x[, .N, by=key_][N > 1]` to view any dupes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `do.call()`, using `.SDcols` to supply the columns.

```
x[, key_ := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "_")), .SDcols = names(x)]
```

`.SDcols = names(x)` supplies all the columns of `x`.  You can supply any vector of names or column numbers there.